# Decoding / Playing back HE-AAC v2 (Parametric Stereo) on iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, decode, audio-streaming, aac

I want to use HE-AAC v2 (Parametric Stereo) audio files in one of my applications, but it appears that iOS (as of the latest version) does not support it – those files play back as if they were mono, presumably because the decoder doesn't understand the Parametric Stereo information stored in the file, and cannot reconstitute the two-channel stereo spread.

I've done some Googling around but it's tricky to find specific information on the v2 codec (as opposed to just HE-AAC v1, which does not allow Parametric Stereo), and I'm wondering if there are any valid third-party software decoders available which would allow me to use HE-AAC v2 files in full stereo on iOS.

Alternatively, is there any other feasible solution to this problem, asides from simply using the v1 (non-Parametric) version of the codec to encode my audio files?

Comment: What version of iOS are you using? iOS 4.3 & above support HE-aac v2

Comment: Do you have anything that backs that up? I’ve not been able to dig up any information to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself, and while trying to do research I found your question, and since I've found the solution, here's the answer:
You're using an encoder that doesn't work quite right. I used to use Premiere Pro for HE-AAC and HE-AACv2 audio and it never properly worked on iOS. However, I eventually found an encoder with HE-AAC that did work on iOS (I used EZ CD Audio Converter).

tl;dr:
Use a different HE-AAC supported encoder, some don't encode it right for iOS to decode properly.